# How to create multiple Many-to-Many relationships using the same join table [EF7/Core]

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Is it possible to create 2 M:M relationships using the same join table?

I have the following situation and am receiving the exception:

`Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.ExpertTags' and 'UserTag.User', because there already is a relationship between 'ApplicationUser.StudyTags' and 'UserTag.User'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship`

In Tag:

```
public class Tag {
    public Tag() {
        Users = new List<UserTag>();
    }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserTag> Users { get; set; }
```

In ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        StudyTags = new HashSet<UserTag>();
        ExpertTags = new HashSet<UserTag>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserTag> StudyTags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserTag> ExpertTags { get; set; }
}
```

In UserTag (CLR join):

```
public class UserTag
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

In ApplicationDbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
            .HasOne(ut => ut.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.StudyTags)
            .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
            .HasOne(ut => ut.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.ExpertTags)
            .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
            .HasOne(ut => ut.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.TagId);
    }
```

Do I need to create separate CLR classes? Something like `UserStudyTag` and `UserExpertTag`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step down to SQL DB. You want to have table `UserTag` with one `UserId` field. How EF should guess, which records in this table are related to `StudyTags` and which to `ExpertTags` collections?

You should duplicate something.

Either split `UserTag` to two tables (`UserStudyTag` and `UserExpertTag`), or make two `UserId` fields in `UserTag`, say `ExpertUserId` and `StudyUserId`. Both nullable, with only one having some value in each record.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using two separate tables.